# Is there a text-fill property in CSS?

Tags: css, specifications

### *Gradient text with shadow* is overcomplicated

```css
h1 {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* Move to h1::before = tiny black border. Remove = black text. */
  position: relative; /* Remove = h1::before overflows to padding of h1's container if text is wrapped. */
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px red; /* Move to h1::before = red text (!), blue-lime inset shadow (!), red shadow. */
  /* filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px red); Multiple values are applied on each other, instead of the text. */
}

h1::before {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, lime);
  -webkit-background-clip: text; /* Works, because -webkit-text-fill-color is inherited from h1. */
  content: attr(data-text); /* Remove = no h1::before = no gradient. */
  position: absolute; /* Remove = separated shadow. */
  text-shadow: none; /* Remove = red text (!), blue-lime inset shadow (!), red shadow. */
}
```

```html
<!-- The data-text attribute is for h1::before {content: attr(data-text);} -->
<h1 data-text="Gradient text with shadow">Gradient text with shadow</h1>
```

### Is there a `text-fill` property in CSS?

```css
h1 {
  text-fill: linear-gradient(blue, lime);
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Gradient text with shadow</h1>
```

- If yes...

  - How is it called? (`text-fill` is unknown property name in Chrome.)
  - Which CSS specification (draft) is it - or will be - part of?
- If no...

  - How can it be requested?
  - Would it be useful (pro/con)?

### `-webkit-text-fill-color` is not enough

It can't be used with gradients, just colors. It's like `background-color`, but I'm looking for something like `background`, which is a shorthand and accepts not only colors, but gradients as well. The `text-fill` I'm looking for might be the shorthand for things like `text-fill-attachment`, `text-fill-clip`, `text-fill-color`, `text-fill-image`, `text-fill-origin`, `text-fill-position`, `text-fill-repeat`, `text-fill-size`, I guess. Or at least `text-fill-gradient`.

Comment: *Gradient text with shadow is overcomplicated* --> The code you provided is actually very simple. There is more complex and overcomplicated code.

Comment: It is very simple to drink water from a deep plate, much simpler than from a pot, but I'd prefer a glass.

Comment: go ahead and add a proposal here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md but make sure you have enough arguments to convince the W3C to consider a new property that will do something we can already do.

Comment: Do you mean that `text-fill`doesn't exist, not even on a different name, not even in a CSS draft, it hasn't even been planned, this is idea totally new, can be proposed on the link above, but seems unnecessary? I'd accept that as an answer. But why do you think that the W3C is focused only on necessary properties, refusing useful ones? I know it's a lot of effort for a tiny improvement, but in my opinion it's not unusual.

Comment: maybe it exists somewhere but I doubt because we already have a property that can do this and it's not a complex one and you imagine how many improvement the W3C is working one so I don't think they will focus on something that we can easily do. Your are simply asking to replace 2 properties with only one.

Comment: I'm asking for 1 property instead of having to use 7 properties plus a pseudo-element with side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but a different idea of code to show that it's not complex or overcomplicated to get a shadow with gradient text

```css
h1 {
  display: grid;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  grid-area: 1 /1;
  color:transparent;
}

/* the gradient */
h1::after {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, lime);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
/* the shadow */
h1::before {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Gradient text with shadow"></h1>
```

And in the near future you can optimize like below (working only on Firefox for now)

```css
h1 {
  display: grid;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  grid-area: 1 /1;
  color:transparent;
}

/* the gradient */
h1::after {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, lime) text;
}
/* the shadow */
h1::before {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Gradient text with shadow"></h1>
```

You have your one line to create a text with gradient coloration.

Answer (score 0):

there's a text-fill-color property in CSS, it is used with -WebKit- extension.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly, that can't be used with gradients, just simple colors. It's like `background-color`, but I'm looking for something like `background`, which is a shorthand and accepts not only simple colors, but gradients as well.

Comment: have u tried the background-image?

background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);

Comment: Thanks, but that affects only the surroundings of the text. `-webkit-background-clip: text` can modify that behaviour to apply the gradient on the text instead, but it requires overcomplicated code. The goal is not only to create a gradient text with shadow, but to use simple code as well.