# Linter message: Unknown property 'text-fill-color' css(unknown properties)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

My navbar is not working and I don't know why. I think it may have to do with this line of code:

```css
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

The line `text-fill-color: transparent;` gives me the message "unknown property 'text-fill-color' css(unknown properties)".

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you also attach the html as well and you can refer this: https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/text-fill-color.html

Comment: It seems it only works with the -webkit- extension : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65823171/8998480

Answer (score 0):

Try
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;